# virtualenv --no-site-packages is not working for me

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages v1

cd v1\Scripts

activate.bat

python -c "import django" # - no problem here
```

Why does it see the Django package??? It should give me an import error, right?

Comment: what `python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"` produces?

Comment: @j.f. : v1\Scripts\python.exe

Comment: @agend: Are sure that it is a new environment? Try to create an environment that doesn't exists already e.g., `virtualenv --no-site-packages 4fd700ca`

Comment: `D:\kod_django>virtualenv --no-site-packages v5

New python executable in v5\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools.....................done.

D:\kod_django>cd v5\Scripts

D:\kod_django\v5\Scripts>activate.bat

(v5) D:\kod_django\v5\Scripts>python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"

D:\kod_django\v5\Scripts\python.exe `

Comment: @j.f. - made a fresh one - didn't change anything, sorry i can't format the last comment correctly

Comment: Did you mess with `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @tomasz - hi, what do you mean by mess with... What should be a correct pythonpath?

Comment: Did you set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable by yourself?

Comment: @tomasz - actually it helped - make a post, i'll mark it as an answer, thanks

Comment: related: `PYTHONPATH` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961103/virtualenv-on-windows-not-over-riding-installed-package/2963017#2963017

Comment: I have a similar problem, and the issue is nothing to do with PYTHONPATH and seems to be that Windows is ignoring the PATH variable. I don't have a fix as yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just unset `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. The idea of virtualenv is that you can create your own environment (fully isolated or extending the default one) so you don't have to mess with that.

As someone noticed there's already been [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961103/virtualenv-on-windows-not-over-riding-installed-package/2963017#2963017).
Read it if you need a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It should not raise any `ImportError` as long as there is a `django` package in the `sys.path`.

If you're wondering where `django` comes from, run:

```
python -c "import django; print django.__file__"
```

Then check Python's [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments: Take into account that the `--no-site-packages` option in virtualenv only removes the standard site-packages directory from `sys.path`. The other paths just remain the same.

Comment: yeah, i know it's coming from somewhere, but i don't want to see it after activating virtualevn environment - what should i do ? do i have to set my python/system path by hand ? i was expecting virtualenv to do it for me

Comment: Yes, virtualenv modifies the module search path (`sys.path`). But finding out where `django` is may help you fix the isolation of packages. The `--no-site-packages` just removes the standard site-packages directory from `sys.path`. Everything else just remains there.